# Event Propagation in Svelte

Tags: onclick, event-handling, svelte, mousedown, event-propagation

When interacting with a child component, the parent component's event triggers. Below is an example of my code:

```
<!-- Parent Component -->
<div class="parent" on:click={toggle}>
     {#if expand}
             <Child />
     {/if}
</div>

<!-- Child Component -->
<div class="child" on:mousedown|stopPropagation={execute}>
     text
</div>
```

I tried using `stopPropagation` and `preventDefault` in-line and in the function calls.

Comment: Do not add `click` events on divs, use `button` elements instead. It is not accessible otherwise.

Comment: Handling `mousedown` is rarely necessary, you might want to ask how to achieve what you are *actually trying to do* here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are different events, stopping one type will not stop the other, even if they both relate to the action of clicking. You would have to stop `click` on the child if you listen to `click` on the parent.

Also, use buttons.

If you only want to trigger the handler on clicks on that specific element, not its descendants, you can also use the [`self` modifier](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#on-eventname), e.g.

```html
<button on:click|self={onClick}>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also check inside your `toggle`-Method, if the clicked element is not a child.

something like:

```
function toggle(e){
   if (e.target.classList.contains("child"))
      return;
}
```